# How do does rooting in Cyanogenmod 10.2 work?

Tags: cyanogenmod

Cyanogenmod 10.2 comes pre-rooted, but some people don't like the built-in SuperUser program, and would like to either update the su binary or use a completely different su program. Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: Are you talking about some custom ROM for 4.3?

Comment: CyanogenMod 10.2

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've taken the liberty of adding that information to your question, to avoid confusing any future visitors, and to make your question easier to find by those who can answer it.

Comment: No, I don't use CM. We do have a few regulars who know much more about it, so I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: At least SuperSU (an alternative to SuperUser) has the feature to replace other SuperUser apps. One normally doesn't care that much about the `su` binary; it's rather the different features of the managers people are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flashing a SuperSU update zip via recovery will override Android 4.3's built-in Superuser. From then on, you can use SuperSU, but you will need to keep Superuser enabled in Settings.